# Store dispatch function not accepting my parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, store

Good day. I am trying to make a quick search function by using axios and it fails whenever i try to pass any parameters to it, however it works just fine when i hard code the values i need to perform the api call, like in the above.

This is my component methods and variables:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    value1: null,
    value2: null,
    value3: null,

  }),

  methods: {
    myMethod(){
      this.$store.dispatch('storeFunction', {functionValue1: this.value1, functionValue2: this.value2, functionValue3: this.value3})
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

This is my Store dispatch function, this one doesnt work and gives me an error 500:

```
    storeFunction(functionValue1, functionValue2, functionValue3) {
      axios
        .post("/some/call", {        
          apiValue1: functionValue1,
          apiValue2: functionValue2,
          apiValue3: functionValue3
         }
           )
        .then(res => {
          console.log("call response", res)
        });
    },
  },
```

However if i hard code the values i need to make this post it works just fine:

```
    storeFunction() {
      axios
        .post("/some/call", {        
          apiValue1: 'myValue1',
          apiValue2: 'myCalue2',
          apiValue3: 'myCalue3'
         }
           )
        .then(res => {
          console.log("call response", res)
        });
    },
  },
```

What i am doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You're dispatching an action with a single object as the parameters:

```
this.$store.dispatch('storeFunction', {functionValue1: this.value1, functionValue2: this.value2, functionValue3: this.value3})
```

But your function accepts three separate parameters:

```
storeFunction(functionValue1, functionValue2, functionValue3)
```

The solution should be just to destructure your parameters in the function, like so:

```
storeFunction({functionValue1, functionValue2, functionValue3})
```

Or, if you are unable to use this feature, you can do it the ES5 way:

```
storeFunction(values) {
  var functionValue1 = values.functionValue1
  var functionValue2 = values.functionValue2
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: neither are working. when i use console.log() on my dispatch function they are all undefined for some reason. which is weird since the console.log() in my compnent shows that the values i am passing to dispatch all exist